# How to cast MySQL result to a string?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

There is a query:

```
SELECT blalist FROM blatable WHERE blafield=714
```

which returns a string that looks like: "2,12,29,714,543,1719". And there is another query:

```
SELECT userid, name, surname, creditcardnum, items
    FROM stolencards WHERE userid IN
    (SELECT blalist FROM blatable WHERE blafield=714)
```

Now that's not working. 
I only managed to get it working by executing these queries separately. What should I do to keep it in a single query?

Comment: In MySQL thete is not any `explode` function. Go with `@Tatu Ulmanen` instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never store more than one value in one cell. Each value in `blatable` should be in its own row, then your `IN` clause would work like a charm. Take a look at database normalization and especially at [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) on how your tables should be designed.

As you have all the values in one cell, doing an `IN` comparison results in all userids being compared to the string "2,12,29,714,543,1719", which obviously will not match. Your query effectively looks like this:

```
...FROM stolencards WHERE userid IN ("2,12,29,714,543,1719")
```

Answer (score 0):

check the data type of blalist and userid are same, or blalist really returns userid?

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified correct data types and pk and fk relationships then try this:

```
SELECT s.userid, s.name, s.surname, s.creditcardnum, s.items
FROM stolencards s inner join blatable b on s.userid = b.blafield
where b.blafield = 714
```